# Having trouble submitting a query that has > and < signs to Bigquery API

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

Our environment uses Python 2.7 along with BigQuery library 0.27.0.

The query that is to be submitted is part of a JSON string which is loaded by

```
json.loads(json_blob)
```

then the value for query is extracted from a key:

```
query_str = json_blob["sql_command"]
```

Printing the `query_str` gives the following value:

```
('query_str: ', '"   select distinct id from my_table where step_count > 3  and lower(name) = \'test\')  "')
```

When the script submits the query for execution as following:

```
job = self.bq_client.run_async_query(job_id, query_str, udf_resources=udf_obj, query_parameters=query_params)
```

BigQuery job comes back with an error, and when I lookup the job information using the `job_id` on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get I see that the query that is actually executed is as following:

```
select distinct id from my_table where step_count \u003e 3  and lower(name) = 'test')
```

I have read on encoding/decoding and tried them, and doesn't make a diference.

Is there a way that I can convert that `query_str` retrieved from the json_blob (`query_str = json_blob["sql_command"]`) to a true string?  We know that when we define such query as a string (hard-coded in the script rather than retrieved from a key in a JSON blob) the query gets executed successfully, ex.

```
query_str = """select distinct  id from my_table where step_count > 3  and lower(name) = 'test')"""
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this using Python 2.7:

```
$ python
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>> import json
>>> client = bigquery.Client('<project name redacted>')
>>> json_blob = json.loads('{"sql_command":"select distinct id from my_table where step_count > 3  and lower(name) = \'test\'"}')
>>> query_str = json_blob["sql_command"]
>>> query_job = client.query(query_str)
>>> rows = query_job.result()
```

I get an error that `my_table` can't be resolved (as expected), but no syntax error. Syntax validation happens prior to table resolution. Checking the job information, I see:

```
$ bq --format=prettyjson show -j <job id>
{
  "configuration": {
    "query": {
      "priority": "INTERACTIVE", 
      "query": "select distinct id from my_table where step_count > 3  and lower(name) = 'test'", 
      "useLegacySql": false
    }
  },
```

so there was no problem with passing the query to BigQuery. Some suggestions:

- Check the code points in the string; maybe it doesn't have the content that you think it does:

  ```
  print [ord(c) for c in query_str]
  ```

The code point for the greater than sign is 62, for example, so you should see it in the output.

- Pick a different serialization format rather than JSON and see if that affects the result. Maybe something else in your process is performing escaping without you realizing it, and you can identify the source of the problem by using e.g. [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) instead and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks much for your reponse, you were right, that was not the real problem.